# Scala: two sliding more efficiently

Tags: scala

I am working on the Quick Start of Apache Spark. I was wondering about efficiency of transformations on collections. I would like to know how to improve the following code:

```
// Variable initialisation
val N = 300.0
val input = (0.0 to N-1 by 1.0).toArray
val firstBigDivi = 100
val windowDuration = 6
val windowStep = 3

// Process
val windowedInput = inputArray.
sliding(firstBigDivi,firstBigDivi).toArray. //First, a big division
map(arr=>arr.sliding(windowDuration,windowStep).toArray)//Second, divide the division
```

Is there another way to do the same more efficiently? I think this code iterates twice over the input array (which could be an issue for big collections) is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sliding` creates an [Iterator](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/IterableLike.html#sliding(size:Int,step:Int):Iterator[Repr]), so mapping that would be "cheap". You have a superfluous `.toArray` though between `sliding` and `map`. It suffices

```
val windowedInputIt = input.
sliding(firstBigDivi,firstBigDivi) //First, a big division
.map(arr=>arr.sliding(windowDuration,windowStep).toArray)
```

Then you can evaluate that iterator into an Array by writing

```
val windowedInput = windowedInputIt.toArray
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If I understood correctly I can only save a conversion? What about the second question? Do I really need to iterate twice?

Comment: You want to build an array of arrays - so there is no way you can't iterate once over the inner structure and once over the outer structure. I don't see how can save more operations. Of course if you have arrays, you can construct the output array imperatively without sliding and map, iterating by hand.

Comment: And do you think it could be less expensive iterating by hand?

Comment: @PaNh yes, of course, creating the output `Array` once with the known size and populating it through `while` loops is certainly much faster. The question is if you _need_ that speed. I would always caution against these things that quickly turn out as instances of "premature optimisation". Better have a concise and readable code base if the performance is not a bottle neck, because then you retain maintainable code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, for the time being I do not really need this optimisation but in the future if I want to process a big amount of data it could be an issue. One more question about your `while` loop, if I use the slice method on the array to divide to populate the output array, would it be efficient?